# sincedb_path in Windows OS

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

I am learning ELK. I read tutorial https://www.zenitk.com/import-from-csv-to-elasticsearch-with-logstash . The tutorial use Linux OS, while I am using Windows OS.

From tutorial

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/zenitk/hackernews.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}

filter {

    csv {
        columns => [
            "id","by","score","time","time_ts","title",
            "url","text","deleted","dead","descendants","author"
        ]
        separator => ","
        skip_header => true
    }

    date {
        match => ["time_ts", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"]
        target => "post_date"
        remove_field => "time_ts"
    }

    mutate {        
        rename => { 
            "dead" => "is_dead"
            "id" => "[@metadata][id]"            
        }
        
        convert => {
            "is_dead" => "boolean"
        }
       
        remove_field => [
            "@timestamp", 
            "host",
            "message", 
            "@version", 
            "path", 
            "descendants",
            "time"
            "id"
        ]
    }
}

output {

  elasticsearch { 
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      index => "hackernews_import"
      document_id => "%{[@metadata][id]}"
  }

  stdout {}
}
```

In Windows OS, what is equivalent with `sincedb_path => "/dev/null"`?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows equivalent is

```
sincedb_path => "NUL"
```

Three letters, upper case. This will prevent the in-memory sincedb being persisted across restarts. An in-memory sincedb is *always* used.